# SwiftUI FetchRequest and onReceive cause infinite loop

Tags: loops, core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I have a @FetchRequest for NSManagedObject in swiftUI. I’m trying to change the title of the first item in core data when the toggle is used, by calling onReceive. This *does not* work if the fetched results are used in MainVC. To demonstrate this, the Navigation Buttons title is how many elements are in the fetched result. This ends up creating an infinite loop in the ContentView onRecieve method. If the Navigation Button has regular text instead of using anything from the FetchedResults then there is no loop and everything works as expected. How is this loop being caused, and is there any better way of toggling a specific core data element?

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

final class ContentVCModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published var newToDoItem = String()
    @Published var shouldTurnOn = false

    func createNewToDoItem(){
        let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let toDoItem = ToDoItem(context: moc)
        toDoItem.title = self.newToDoItem
        toDoItem.createdAt = Date()
        toDoItem.cost = Cost(main: "$\(Int.random(in: 1...99))", tax: "$\(Int.random(in: 1...9))")
        toDoItem.isOn = false

        ToDoItem.save()
        self.newToDoItem = ""
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = ContentVCModel()
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDoItems()) var toDoItems : FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

    var body: some View {
        List{
            Section(header : Text("Whats next?")){
                Toggle("Toggle Test", isOn: $model.shouldTurnOn)
                    .onReceive(model.$shouldTurnOn) { (newValue) in
                        self.toDoItems.first?.title = "\(Int.random(in: 23...3423))"
                        //infitine loop
                }
                HStack{
                    TextField("New Item", text: $model.newToDoItem)
                        Button(action: {
                            self.model.createNewToDoItem()
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(self.model.newToDoItem.isEmpty ? .gray : .green)
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }.disabled(self.model.newToDoItem.isEmpty)
                    }
                }.font(.headline)
                Section(header: Text("To Do's")){
                    ForEach(toDoItems) { toDoItem in
                        ToDoItemView(title: toDoItem.title, createdAt: toDoItem.createdAt.description, cost: toDoItem.cost, isOn: true)
                    }.onDelete { (indexSet) in
                        let deleteItem = self.toDoItems[indexSet.first!]
                        self.managedObjectContext.delete(deleteItem)
                        ToDoItem.save()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("My List"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
}


struct MainVC : View {
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDoItems()) var toDoItems : FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                Text("\(toDoItems.count)") //Using toDoItems causes this to repeat ex: "\(toDoItems.count)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question?